# Tkinter canvas.create_image cutting off pixels?

Tags: python, tkinter

So I'm very new to Python, and just started working with Tkinter... Already having problems.

I have a bunch of code... But the bit that's giving me a problem is:

```
self.menuCanvas = Canvas(self.menuFrame, width=100, height=600)
self.menuCanvas.pack()
self.menuBGpath = getDir() + "/Resources/" + "menuOne.gif"
self.menuBGimg = Image("photo", file=self.menuBGpath)
self.menuBackground = self.menuCanvas.create_image(0,0,anchor=NW, image=self.menuBGimg)
```

The image I'm trying to display is this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Nczt.gif

Notice how on the left side and bottom  it has a black line, 1 pixel wide. I want that in the final program to help it look clean.

The problem is... When I execute the .py, this is what displays: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6gWc.png

There's no black line along the left or bottom, and it's instead replaced with a white line (Guessing that's the background, even tho I have everything set to padx=0 and pady=0, 0,0 for the image creation, etc...)

How do I fix this/what am I doing wrong?

Edit: So I did some more tinkering and found that if I draw it at 2,2 instead of 0,0 it displays properly. It's inside 2 frames (mainFrame which is the whole window size for that particular function, menuFrame which is to distinguish the side menu from the main content frame), which I'm guessing each frame is for some reason reserving a pixel border of 1. Is there any way I can tell it to *stop* reserving that 1 pixel per frame?

Comment: Set `highlightthickness=0` when creating the canvas.

Comment: So that fixed me being able to change the co-ordinates for the create_image back to 0,0, and I no longer have dead space at the bottom of the screen... But I still have 2 pixels of dead space on the left hand side of the screen. The image is 97 pixels wide, I have that frame set to 99 pixel width (and changed the canvas size to 99 pixels instead of 100), but if I put it to 98 it cuts off the right side of the image. How do I get rid of those two dead columns of pixels so I can just have the frame and canvas both be 97 pixels?

Comment: This is another question that you need to provide [mre].